# CSS layout: align elements in the right order

Tags: css, layout, html-table, css-selectors

I need some layout help.
The container below ( .webdevelopment ) should look like this: 
the headline should be aligned in the center 100% width; then the two "innhaltbox" div´s 50% and then the skilltabele with 100% and the childs should have spacearound. I guess i have some selector issues some help would be nice.

```
  <div id="Webdevelopment">
            <div class="titel">Webdevelopment</div>
            <div class="inhalt">
              <div class="inhaltbox_1">

              </div>
              <div class="inhaltbox_2">
                <ul>
                  <li>Kreatives Webdesign</li>
                  <li>Große Erfahrung mit Virtual Reality</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill">
              <table>
                <caption>skill</caption>
                <tr class="skillname">
                  <th>html</th>
                  <th>css</th>
                  <th>javascript</th>
                  <th>aframe</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="skillicons">
                  <td>icon</td>
                  <td>icon</td>
                  <td>icon</td>
                  <td>icon</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sterne">
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</td>
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</td>
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</td>
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
```

here some css:

```
.title {
  width: 100%;
  }

.inhalt {
  content: "";
  width:100%;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.inhaltbox {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.skill {
  justify-content: space-around;
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```css
.title {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  }

.inhalt {
  width:100%;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.inhaltbox {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.skill {
  justify-content: space-around;
  width:100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Webdevelopment">
            <div class="title">Webdevelopment</div>
            <div class="inhalt">
              <div class="inhaltbox_1 inhaltbox">
                 <ul>
                  <li>Kreatives Webdesign</li>
                  <li>Große Erfahrung mit Virtual Reality</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <div class="inhaltbox_2 inhaltbox">
                <ul>
                  <li>Kreatives Webdesign</li>
                  <li>Große Erfahrung mit Virtual Reality</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="skill">
              <table>
                <caption>skill</caption>
                <tr class="skillname">
                  <th>html</th>
                  <th>css</th>
                  <th>javascript</th>
                  <th>aframe</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="skillicons">
                  <td>icon</td>
                  <td>icon</td>
                  <td>icon</td>
                  <td>icon</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="sterne">
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</td>
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</td>
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9734;</td>
                  <td>&#9733; &#9733; &#9733;</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
here some css:
```